# Open terminal/prompt and pass a comand (ping)

Tags: java, bash, cmd, terminal, prompt

I need some help with my Java desktop application.

I have a button that calls (is my intention) the terminal (Linux) or prompt/cmd (Windows) and pass some command (I'm trying to use the ping command).

I just know how to open the terminal, but I can't pass the command. How I do this?

Thanks.

**Edited:**

My code at this time:

```
       Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
       String sistemaOperacional = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
            String ip = "192.168.7.1";
            String comando  = "ping -c 100 "+ip;

            if (sistemaOperacional.contains("linux")){
                try {
                    rt.exec("gnome-terminal ");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if (sistemaOperacional.contains("win")){

                try {
                    rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start command");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível identificar o sistema operacional!");
            }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code which is launching the terminal or command prompt?

Comment: Edited. This calls the terminal, but without command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search the documentation for your terminal for the option that sets the command that will be run on terminal startup. For example, for `xterm` it is `-e`, so to run a command from Java code in `xterm` you would do, for example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xterm -e ls;read"); // read is here just for the terminal not to close right away
```

To pop up a terminal, run `ls` and wait for user to press enter until the terminal closes.

But since you shouldn't rely on your user to have a certain default terminal, you'd better be using system default, and `-e` is the standard parameter among many terminals (`gnome-terminal` uses it as well, for example):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("x-terminal-emulator -e ls;read");
```

Comment: In the place that you put "read" is there where I pass my var content?

Comment: You can put any command after `-e`. Since command is just a string, you can compose that command within your Java code using your variables, yes. I put `read` just so the terminal wouldn't close right after popping up. There's probably a better way for keeping the terminal with provided `-e` argument open (if you need that, of course), but I didn't find one.

Comment: Yes, it's works (on Linux). I tried with `ping`command and works.
`"x-terminal-emulator -e"+command`. In Windows, can I try the same thing?

Comment: @Tux123 Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Windows's `cmd` or whatever their terminal emulator is, try searching for it yourself and post additional questions if you get stuck. Also accepting the useful answer never hurts ; )

Comment: @Tux123 Wait, you already know it is`cmd /c command`, just do `"cmd /c"+ command` in your java code.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that on windows.

Comment: For windows, this works:
`rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start "+comand);`
Thanks ;)